# Question specification and numbering in exam class

Tags: numbering, exam

I want to make a course book with exercises and examples, and my question is how can I make a name for question for instance 'Exercise 1.15' where 1.15 is question number for exercise 15 in section 1, and in the next section there would be 'Exercise 2.15'. Does anybody has an idea, how can I make it?

Comment: You might also look at packages like examdesign, which work with other document classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\thequestion}{Excersise \thesection.\arabic{question}}


\begin{document}
  \section{Section}
    \begin{questions}
        \question This is question 1 of Section 1
        \question This is question 2 of Section 1
    \end{questions}
  \section{Section}
    \begin{questions}
        \question This is question 1 of Section 2
        \question This is question 2 of Section 2
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeeessss, this is exactly what I want, thank you veeryy much

Comment: @Michal Szymankiewicz: You are welcome!